# What in the SQL or PostgreSQL specification explains comparison of arrays vs primitives?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I'm looking to understand why exactly you can compare nulls as equal inside arrays, but not as primitives.

For example, the following query demonstrates:

```
SELECT NULL = NULL AS does_not_equal
     , NULL::bool = NULL::bool AS does_equal
     , NULL::int =  NULL::int AS does_equal
     , NULL::text = NULL::text AS does_equal
     , ARRAY[NULL] = ARRAY[NULL] AS does_equal
     , ARRAY[NULL]::bool[] = ARRAY[NULL]::bool[] AS does_equal
     , ARRAY[NULL]::int[] = ARRAY[NULL]::int[] AS does_equal
     , ARRAY[NULL]::text[] = ARRAY[NULL]::text[] AS does_equal
;
```

I understand why NULL = NULL is NULL for primitives, and I also think I understand why comparing composite types will give a true comparison for a field in them that is null on both sides, primarily because of the *= operator that looks at the binary value of the type.  But arrays don't seem to use the *= operator, and I haven't been able to find anything explaining it so far in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a complicated story.

Here is what the SQL standard (ISO/IEC 9075-2) sayeth in section “8.2
<comparison predicate>”:

> Let *XV* and *YV* be two values represented by <value expression>s *X* and *Y*, respectively. The result of:
>
> `X <comp op> Y`
>
> is determined as follows:
>   Case:
>
> 1. If either *XV* or *YV* is the null value, then
>
>    `X <comp op> Y`
>
>    is Unknown.
> 2. Otherwise,
>
>    Case:
>
>    1. If the declared types of *XV* and *YV* are row types with degree *N*, then let *X<sub>i</sub>*, 1 (one) ≤ *i* ≤ *N*,
>         denote a <value expression> whose value and declared type is that of the *i*-th field of *XV* and
>         let *Y<sub>i</sub>* denote a <value expression> whose value and declared type is that of the *i*-th field of *YV*.
>         The result of
>
>       `X <comp op> Y`
>
>       is determined as follows:
>
>       1. *X* = *Y* is *True* if and only if *X<sub>i</sub>* = *Y<sub>i</sub>* is *True* for all *i*.
>       2. *X* < *Y* is *True* if and only if *X<sub>i</sub>* = *Y<sub>i</sub>* is *True* for all *i* < *n* and *X<sub>n</sub>* = *Y<sub>n</sub>* for some *n*.
>       3. *X* = *Y* is *False* if and only if NOT (*X<sub>i</sub>* = *Y<sub>i</sub>*) is *True* for some *i*.
>       4. *X* < *Y* is *False* if and only if *X* = *Y* is *True* or *Y* < *X* is *True*.
>       5. *X* <comp op> *Y* is *Unknown* if *X* <comp op> *Y* is neither *True* nor *False*.
>    2. If the declared types of *XV* and *YV* are array types with cardinalities *N1* and *N2*, respectively,
>         then let *X<sub>i</sub>*, 1 (one) ≤ *i* ≤ *N1*, denote a <value expression> whose value and declared type is that
>         of the *i*-th element of *XV* and let *Y<sub>i</sub>* denote a <value expression> whose value and declared type
>         is that of the *i*-th element of *YV*. The result of
>
>       `X <comp op> Y`
>
>       is determined as follows:
>
>       1. *X* = *Y* is *True* if *N1* = 0 (zero) and *N2* = 0 (zero).
>       2. *X* = *Y* is *True* if *N1* = *N2* and, for all *i*, *X<sub>i</sub>* = *Y<sub>i</sub>* is *True*.
>       3. *X* = *Y* is *False* if and only if *N1* ≠ *N2* or NOT (*X<sub>i</sub>* = *Y<sub>i</sub>*) is *True*, for some *i*.
>       4. *X* <comp op> *Y* is *Unknown* if *X* <comp op> *Y* is neither *True* nor *False*.

That is pretty confusing, for example I see no specification hoz wo compare arrays with other than equality operators.

The standard also contradicts itself occasionally.

The `*=` operator only exists for `record`, not for arrays. It does pretty much the same as `=`, but is more efficient, as it doesn't “detoast” values if their length is different.

The best is to accept the semantics as they are.

PostgreSQL doesn't seem to follow the standard in this.

NULL by itself is confusing, NULL in composites or arrays even more so.

Comment: Thank you very much.  My purpose for asking was to determine if I could rely on the fact that I can get the desired boolean comparison result out of a set of array values even though I would get an unknown result if the values were not in an array such as if evaluated in a row context after an unnest().

Comment: As you have found out, the result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find documentation for the behavior that you describe.  However, `NULL`s are considered equal for record and row constructors, and this is explained explicitly:

> The SQL specification requires row-wise comparison to return NULL if
>   the result depends on comparing two NULL values or a NULL and a
>   non-NULL. . . . In other contexts where two composite-type values are
>   compared, two NULL field values are considered equal, and a NULL is
>   considered larger than a non-NULL.

An array is not a composite type.  It would seem that similar logic is being used.